# Replace third character from a 4-digit string with another in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

My goal is to mask one digit from a 4-digit string. Instead of having `2451`, I'd like to have `24*1`.

I tried `{{ my_var|replace(slice(2, 1): '*') }}` but this raises the following error: `The function "slice" does not exist in My:Bundle:file.html.twig`.

The weirdest thing being that `{{ my_var|slice(2, 1) }}` works perfectly. So the function **does** exists.

How can I do what I want to achieve?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Your own Twig extension - filter: 
[SymfonyCookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)
IMHO it would be cleanest way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll go read the documentation you've provided and let you know my choice of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

`slice` is a filter not a function, you can try to pipe them but in your case i do not see something achievable without creating your custom `twig` function or filter to `mask` your needs:

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I start thinking I'd go for a Twig extension but what do you mean by `you can try to pipe them`?

Comment: Pipe is the `I` caracter, that comes from linux systems, that means that you can stack more filters from left to right, `myvar|slice(2,1)|replace('foo': "bar")`, first `slice`, than `replace` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for that. I decided to go for a Twig extension anyway. I'll accept the other answer though, which provided documentation that was helpful.